# Client Cannot find "AuthenticaionService.init"

Tags: javascript, html, runtime-error, blazor-webassembly

When I run my application, the browser console throws three, identical errors stating `Could not find 'AuthenticationService.init' ('AuthenticationService' was undefined).` and `Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'AuthenticationService.init' ('AuthenticationService' was undefined).`

However, I cannot find any reference to `AuthenticationService.init`, only `AuthenticationService.js`, nor can I find any documentation of it anywhere, so I'm wondering if this might mean that I have swapped ".js" with ".init", but I can't find a single file in my entire solution (even looking on file explorer) that ends with ".init".

I have checked index.html and it specifically refers to

```
    <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js" />
```

as usual.

I see no reference to AuthenticationService.init anywhere and can't find JSInterop.JSException.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a client-side Blazor project written in .NET 7. I've stumbled upon the same error lately. In my case it was an incorrect link to the AuthenticationService.js.

The correct one is

```
<script src="_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
```